# TStringList and TThread that does not free all of its memory

Tags: delphi, memory, ram, tstringlist, tthread

**Version used:** Delphi 7.

I'm working on a program that does a simple *for* loop on a Virtual ListView. The data is stored in the following record:

```
type TList=record
  Item:Integer;
  SubItem1:String;
  SubItem2:String;
end;
```

*Item* is the index. *SubItem1* the status of the operations (success or not). *SubItem2* the path to the file. The *for* loop loads each file, does a few operations and then, save it. The operations take place in a TStringList. Files are about 2mb each.

Now, if I do the operations on the main form, it works perfectly.

Multi-threaded, there is a huge memory problem. Somehow, the TStringList doesn't seem to be freed completely. After 3-4k files, I get an EOutofMemory exception. Sometimes, the software is stuck to 500-600mb, sometimes not. In any case, the TStringList always return an EOutofMemory exception and no file can be loaded anymore. On computers with more memory, it takes longer to get the exception.

The same thing happens with other components. For instance, if I use *THTTPSend* from Synapse, well, after a while, the software cannot create any new threads because the memory consumption is too high. It's around 500-600mb while it should be, max, 100mb. On the main form, everything works fine.

I guess the mistake is on my side. Maybe I don't understand threads enough. I tried to free everything on the *Destroy* event. I tried *FreeAndNil* procedure. I tried with only one thread at a time. I tried freeing the thread manually (no *FreeOnTerminate*...)

No luck.

So here is the thread code. It's only the basic idea; not the full code with all the operations. If I remove the *LoadFile* prodecure, everything works good. A thread is created for each file, according to a thread pool.

```
unit OperationsFiles;

interface

uses Classes, SysUtils, Windows;

type
 TOperationFile = class(TThread)
 private
  Position : Integer;
  TPath, StatusMessage: String;
  FileStringList: TStringList;
  procedure UpdateStatus;
  procedure LoadFile;
 protected
  procedure Execute; override;
 public
  constructor Create(Path: String; LNumber: Integer);
 end;

implementation

uses Form1;

procedure TOperationFile.LoadFile;
begin
 try
  FileStringList.LoadFromFile(TPath);
  // Operations...
  StatusMessage := 'Success';
 except
  on E : Exception do StatusMessage := E.ClassName;
 end;
end;

constructor TOperationFile.Create(Path : String; LNumber: Integer);
begin
 inherited Create(False);
 TPath := Path;
 Position := LNumber;
 FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TOperationFile.UpdateStatus;
begin
 FileList[Position].SubItem1 := StatusMessage;
 Form1.ListView4.UpdateItems(Position,Position);
end;

procedure TOperationFile.Execute;
begin
 FileStringList:= TStringList.Create;
 LoadFile;

 Synchronize(UpdateStatus);

 FileStringList.Free;
end;

end.
```

What could be the problem?

I thought at one point that, maybe, too many threads are created. If a user loads 1 million files, well, ultimately, 1 million threads is going to be created -- although, only 50 threads **are created and running at the same time**.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: @TLama Already did that... and according to FastMM, there is no memory leak, except the ones from Delphi 7.

Comment: @TLama
13 - 20 bytes: AnsiString x 1
29 - 36 bytes: Unknown x 1
45 - 52 bytes: TStringList x 2
I believe these are memory leaks from Delphi itself. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I've never experienced any memory leaks from Delphi its self.

Comment: Fastmm can provide a call stack of leaked memory allocations, make sure that you have the full version of Fastmm installed. Aside from that, you did not show how the `FileList` is being populated. I suspect that your thread code is throwing an exception you don't handle, bypassing your call to `TStringList.Free()`. Either add a `try/finally` block, or override `DoTerminate()`, to make sure `Free()` is always called.

Comment: @Jerry The RTL/VCL in older Delphis leaked. Emba started fixing these leaks when they started using FastMM.

Comment: The purpose of a thread pool is to reuse the threads, since creating/destroying threads is a heavy task for the system. I suspect the reason with your failing code can be how you are handling the pool.

Comment: @LURD If there is a one-to-one mapping between threads and jobs then this is not a pool in the true meaning of the word, which is your point I guess  ;-)

Comment: I dont see a try finally section for FileStringList, so a leak is possible...

Comment: @whosrdaddy It would be better with a try/finally, but the exception swallowing behaviour of `TOperationFile.LoadFile` effectively means that it won't leak the string list.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and what if updatestatus fails?? (invalid position for example)?? Anyway he's not showing the real code so we could be chasing ghosts here...

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. If an exception occurs in the main thread while `Synchronize()` is running, `Synchronize()` captures and re-raises it in the context of the thread that called `Synchronize()`. So `LoadFile()` may be catching exceptions, but `UpdateStatus()` is not, which can cause an exception to propegate back into `Execute()` and skip the call to `FileStringList.Free()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are (probably) no leaks in the code you show in the question.

I say probably because an exception raised during the `Execute` could result in a leak. The lifetime of the string list should be protected by a `finally` block.

```
FileStringList:= TStringList.Create;
try
  LoadFile;
  Synchronize(UpdateStatus);
finally
  FileStringList.Free;
end;
```

That said, I expect the exception swallow in `LoadFile` means that you don't leak the string list.

You say that perhaps thousands of threads are created. Each thread reserves memory for its stack, and the default stack size is 1MB. Once you have thousands of 1MB stacks reserved, you can easily exhaust or fragment address space.

I've seen problems due to cavalier creation of threads in the past. For example I had a program that failed when it created and destroyed threads, with never more than 256 threads in existence. This was on a 16 core machine with 4GB address space. You probably have 2GB address space available.

Although you state that no more than 50 threads are in existence at any one moment, I'm not sure how you can be sure of that. Not least, because you have set `FreeOnTerminate` to `True` and thereby surrendered control over the lifetime of your threads.

My guess is that your problems are related to the number of threads you create. One thread per processor will suffice. Re-use your threads. It's expensive to create and destroy a thread for a small task.

If this is not enough to solve your problems then you will need to show the code that manages thread lifetime.

Finally, I wonder how much benefit you will extract from threading this app. If it is IO bound then the threaded version may well be slower!

Comment: I thought the same but look at the question update *only 50 threads are created and running at the same time*.

Comment: @TLama Something doesn't add up does it. The code in the Q doesn't leak. Creating too many threads is an easy way to eat all your virtual address space.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - What failure mode did this program suffer? (Creating/destroying threads, never more than 256?).  I'm fighting a similar issue now - a real-time system which samples data from some hardware about 10 times/sec.  The 3rd party driver (for whatever reason) creates and destroys a thread for each measurement (each taking about 10ms).  After a day or so of running continuously cycling ~ 36000 threads/hour it bogs down to a crawl.  The program is otherwise tight and lean.  Curious what your experience was.

Comment: @J... I don't actually recall the precise failure mode. Certainly one of the Win32 API calls failed which then rippled into a runtime Delphi exception. But I can't recall which API call failed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan fair enough... figured it wouldn't hurt to ask. It's given me something elso to investigate, in any case.

Comment: Well, I'll try to reuse my threads to see if it works. I'll tell you later my results. As for the number of threads running, it doesn't appear on the code, but there is a counter of threads. When a thread has finished its job, the counter is lowered so a new thread can be created. My software does many operations. I agree that the TStringList exemple may not be the best, but it was the easiest for me to show in pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information given, it's not possible to reproduce your error.
Some hints are made by Remy and David which might help you.

Looking at the structure of your program, the flow can be divided into two classical solutions.

The first part where you are delegating tasks to different threads, is a `Single-Producer-Multiple-Consumer` problem.
Here it can be solved by creating a small number of threads, passing them a thread-safe object queue. 
The main thread then pushes the task objects into the queue. The consumer threads takes care of the individual file checking tasks.

The second part where the result is to be transfered to the main thread is a `Multiple-Producer-Single-Consumer` problem.
If you pass a second thread-safe object queue to the threads at initialization, they can easily put the results into the queue. 
Drain the result queue from the main thread within a timer event.